# Order phone numbers lexicographically

Tags: python-2.7

In Python 2,how can i order a big set of numbers(around 500) lexicographically.My number set looks like:
09187788329
02043714140
06751292887
02892175534
04188296506
08279960090
05548958250
03590573588

The desired output would be in the format like:
02043714140
02892175534
03590573588
04188296506
05548958250
06751292887
08279960090
09187788329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Python's `sorted` builtin function on an iterable of your phone numbers.

```
phone = (
  "09187788329 02043714140 06751292887 02892175534 "
  "04188296506 08279960090 05548958250 03590573588"
)

print (
  " ".join(
    sorted(
      phone.split(" ")
    )
  )
)
```